# How to unsubscribe push notification from first vendor in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

In my last version of my Application I used Appoxee to send push notification and in my current version, I wanted to switch to UrbanAirShip so I removed Appoxee from the code and integrated UrbanAirShip.

Now when I upgrade the app, I still receive the push notification from appoxee.
I want my old users (using old version of my app) to receive push notification from appoxee and new users (who is on my latest version) to receive only from UrbanAirShip. How to unsubscribe push notification from first vendor

Comment: What research have you do to try and achieve this?

Comment: @MultiColourPixel  Actually I have gone thru the documentation of the respective vendors and regarding push notification but I need help regarding unsubscribing push notifications for the latest apps and to continue supporting old versions with the first vendor (Appoxee)

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications) on how to unregister from the existing provider, i.e. by calling `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` on the `UIApplication` object.

After you've unregistered, you will have to call the registration for remote notification again and at this point pass in the details for Urban Airship.

From what I understand, the user shouldn't be prompted to approve again, it will just use the existing approval settings for the app.